# Thread.Start(WebRequest.GetResponse) vs. WebRequest.BeginGetResponse

Tags: c#, performance, comparison, webrequest

I want to download a file while displaying on UI the download is in progress. With `WebRequest` I have two options:

1. Use `WebRequest.BeginGetResponse` and related methods.

   Advantage: possibility to display exact progress in bytes.

   Disadvantage: more code to write. As synchronous and asynchronous methods don't mix, I'll need to use `BeginGetResponse`, `BeginRead`, `BeginGetRequestStream`. More things to implement manually, including read buffers, timeouts.
2. Start new thread (or use thread pool), use `WebRequest.GetResponse` and related methods.

   Advantage: no unnecessary code.

   Disadvantage: impossible to show exact progress.

As files to be downloaded are rather small, displaying progress in bytes is advantage, but not crucial. Do I miss something if I use second approach, feature-wise and performance-wise?

Or maybe there's a higher-level widely used wrapper I missed? (`WebClient` doesn't expose `WebRequest`'s properties, so it's unusable for me, because I need to use cookies etc.)

Comment: why it is impossible to show exact progress?

Comment: @HPT I think `GetResponse` returns only when request is completely performed. So it's 0% before calling it and 100% after, with nothing in between. Am I wrong?

Comment: yes you are right, my fault, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create a new thread (option no 2) that thread will block while doing the request. If you only make one request at a time that won't matter much, but if you do lots of requests you might end up with lots of extra threads. Each thread will cost you ~1MB RAM.

Asynchronous calls like `WebRequest.BeginGetResponse` will not block any of your threads while the request is in process, it will only pick a thread from the thread pool when your request is completed to deliver the result.

Comment: Are you sure `WebRequest` won't use threads while downloading? I thought it picks a thread from the thread pool when it starts downloading. What's the point in using threads just to deliver result?

Comment: @Athari, Async I/O uses [I/O Completion Port](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365198.aspx) under the hood. That is "async" all the way down to the hardware/network card and "borrows" a thread from the thread pool only when there is actual work to do.